# how to find MyMusic Folder from other users?

Tags: c#, winapi, special-folders

how to find MyMusic Folder of other users ?

Comment: Which OS? The users folder is in a different location on Windows 7 and XP.

Comment: @ChrisF Judging by the response to my question, looks like he is looking for a version-agnostic method of doing it, which with windows api kinda sucks.

Comment: @ChrisF *response to my answer , not my question.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059460/shgetfolderpath-for-a-specific-user

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the account you are running the program on has administrative privlieges, can't you just navigate to `c:\Users\<UserName>\Music`(which is the path on Windows7).
If you're looking for folders of users on another machine, then that is more difficult.

**EDIT:**
It appears that there is a way to do this, [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188(v=VS.85).aspx):

```
HRESULT SHGetKnownFolderPath(
  __in   REFKNOWNFOLDERID rfid,
  __in   DWORD dwFlags,
  __in   HANDLE hToken,
  __out  PWSTR *ppszPath
);
```

With the rfid being the KNOWNFOLDERID of the folder you are looking for in the case of My Music:

```
GUID{2112AB0A-C86A-4FFE-A368-0DE96E47012E}
Display NameMusicFolder 
Type PERUSER
Default Path: %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\Music.library-msCSIDL 
Equivalent None, new in Windows 7
Legacy Display Name Not applicable
Legacy Default Path Not applicable
```

Comment: may be I do not use windows 7 or user hast changed MusicFolder path .

Comment: then, this is a trickier problem than this solution will allow, but that is the default path.

Comment: @pedram, try this new function

Comment: This answer assumes that the default folders are correct.  A users' profile does not have to reside on `C:\Users`.  The remainder of the answer provides an MSDN link and a function from kernel32.dll, but no way to use it.  Yes, the MSDN site has documentation, but it references several other functions and doesn't provide a complete workable solution, particularly in C#.  Because this answer is terribly incomplete, I'm downvoting it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Environment.SpecialFolder` enum along with `Environment.GetFolderPath` to get access to "special" user folders, like so:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic);
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure if "other users" referred to "users other than myself" (i.e. whoever runs the application, or "users other than the user accessing the application".

Answer (score 1):

The documented way to do this is to use [SHGetFolderLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762180(v=VS.85).aspx) and the hToken parameter, the problem is that you need the username and password to call LogonUser (You could also call [WTSQueryUserToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383840(v=VS.85).aspx) if you are running as a service, but that limits you to the currently active sessions)

Now you are left with using [undocumented stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059460/shgetfolderpath-for-a-specific-user):

1. Find the profile: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` (%windir%\Profiles on Win9x)
2. AdjustTokenPrivileges for `SE_RESTORE_NAME`
3. RegLoadKey NTUSER.DAT (USER.DAT on 9x)
4. Query `HKEY_USERS\{SIDYOUGOTFROMPROFILELIST}\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`

Note: You need to be admin to do this and it only works for local accounts.