# Resolving Windows 7 special Paths

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, io

I'm having a problem with Windows 7 paths that can really be used to launch files etc, for example

"C:\Users\mattias\My Pictures\manual.pdf"

the actual location is

"c:\Users\mattias\Documents\My Pictures\manual.pdf"

This is probably because Windows 7 uses libraries, but I need a good way to resolve these kinds of paths to the actual path. I could hack something together Environment.SpecialFolder but it doesn't seem like a good solution since it doesnt take the user into account, The solution should also work under Vista. Do I have to mess around with the Windows API Code Pack and check windows versions or is there a better solution=

Comment: This has nothing to do with libraries, but instead that a displayed path can be different from the actual file system path (e.g. localised).

Comment: @konrad: it *does* take the user into account

Comment: yeah, but what if the path is a different account then the current user

Comment: For other users see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493607/how-to-find-mymusic-folder-from-other-users

Comment: Then you won't be able to access it anyway. Even if you were able to figure out its physical location.

Answer (score 3):

This should get you the actual path:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
```

Just change the MyPictures if you need a different location.

Comment: As I said, I can probably hack together something with Environment.Specialfolder but it doesn't seem like a really good solution since it'll be hard to cover all scenarios

Comment: I don't see what the issue with `SpecialFolder` is. It gets the drive, username and directory for you, what could be easier?

Comment: You'd need to check each path and see if it's legal and manipulate it differently depending on what directory they're trying to access, I want something like GetRealPath(path)